# Animation not showing when ajax request in pace.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, pace.js

In my website http://www.eventiame.com/publicar/ there's a form with several fields. 
When the page loads it shows the pace animation (it does some ajax request when loading so that's ok) but when I submit the form (I do it via ajax too) the animation doesn't appear. 
I tested uploading an image (so it would take longer) and still no animation is shown.
I also tried changing the "async" parameter to true or false in the akax request but still no good.

Here's the specific code for the ajax call which is not working:

```
$.post('Sample.php,$(this).serialize(),function(data){
    $(target).html(data);
},'html');
```

Comment: Typo? Shouldn't it be `'sample.php'`?

Comment: it is not work with $.post or $.ajax()

Comment: same here it does not accept post request but it accept get request :)

Answer (score 6):

You may try this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() { 
       Pace.restart(); 
});
```

I had this same problem and I found a solution in Pace issues section. [Source](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues/110)

Comment: This should be added in the official documentation. Thanks for this easy solution!

Answer (score 5):

*I hope my answer is not too late, but in case of those that might still need it, i had thesame issue also and i solved it.*

By default, Pace will show any ajax requests which begin as a part of a normal or ajax-y page load, or which last longer than 500ms. your ajax request didnt trigger the pace because it's too soon.

**1, Modify the Pace.js :**

Find `restartOnRequestAfter`under the `defaultOptions`and change it to desire time (in milliseconds) value `5` ms.

```
  restartOnRequestAfter: 5,
```

**2, Tracking:**

By default, Pace will only track `GET` HTTP method, so add all other method you might need such as `POST` request.

```
ajax: {
  trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'REMOVE'],
  ...
}
```

**SOURCE:** http://github.hubspot.com/pace/

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing closing single quote, should be:

```
$.post('Sample.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
    $(target).html(data);
}, 'html');
```